# Got Error on Creating Simple Compiler Using Flex and Bison

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer

I'm trying to run simple compiler from [Compiler Construction using Flex and Bison](http://foja.dcs.fmph.uniba.sk/kompilatory/docs/compiler.pdf) Book but there are a lot of error i just write down the code from book. I am not an expert in flex and bison I tried to fix it but I can't.

[here are codes](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5yldipz587681qw/AAClE3TOWuLBKOno_n_3u-XMa?dl=0) that I tried to run and this is the error.

```
root@Tom:/home/karo/Desktop# bison -dv Simple.y 
Simple.y: warning: 39 shift/reduce conflicts [-Wconflicts-sr]
root@Tom:/home/karo/Desktop# gcc -c Simple.tab.c 
In file included from Simple.y:6:0:
SM.h: In function ‘fetch_execute_cycle’:
SM.h:55:4: warning: format ‘%s’ expects a matching ‘char *’ argument [-Wformat=]
    default : printf( "%sInternal Error: Memory Dump\n" ); break;
    ^
In file included from Simple.y:7:0:
CG.h: In function ‘print_code’:
CG.h:28:3: warning: format ‘%ld’ expects argument of type ‘long int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
   printf("%3ld: %-10s%4ld\n",i,op_name[(int) code[i].op], code[i].arg );
   ^
CG.h:28:3: warning: format ‘%ld’ expects argument of type ‘long int’, but argument 4 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
Simple.tab.c: At top level:
Simple.tab.c:158:15: error: stray ‘#’ in program
 typedef union #line 37 "Simple.y" /* yacc.c:355  */
               ^
Simple.tab.c:158:21: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before numeric constant
 typedef union #line 37 "Simple.y" /* yacc.c:355  */
                     ^
Simple.tab.c:161:7: error: stray ‘#’ in program
 union #line 37 "Simple.y" /* yacc.c:355  */
       ^
Simple.tab.c:161:13: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before numeric constant
 union #line 37 "Simple.y" /* yacc.c:355  */
             ^
Simple.tab.c:178:1: error: unknown type name ‘YYSTYPE’
 extern YYSTYPE yylval;
 ^
Simple.tab.c:354:3: error: unknown type name ‘YYSTYPE’
   YYSTYPE yyvs_alloc;
   ^
Simple.tab.c:683:52: error: unknown type name ‘YYSTYPE’
 yy_symbol_value_print (FILE *yyoutput, int yytype, YYSTYPE const * const yyvaluep)
                                                    ^
Simple.tab.c:702:46: error: unknown type name ‘YYSTYPE’
 yy_symbol_print (FILE *yyoutput, int yytype, YYSTYPE const * const yyvaluep)
                                              ^
Simple.tab.c:740:39: error: unknown type name ‘YYSTYPE’
 yy_reduce_print (yytype_int16 *yyssp, YYSTYPE *yyvsp, int yyrule)
                                       ^
Simple.tab.c:1020:44: error: unknown type name ‘YYSTYPE’
 yydestruct (const char *yymsg, int yytype, YYSTYPE *yyvaluep)
                                            ^
Simple.tab.c:1027:16: error: expected end of line before ‘push’
   YY_IGNORE_MAYBE_UNINITIALIZED_BEGIN
                ^
Simple.tab.c:1027:16: error: expected end of line before ‘ignored’
Simple.tab.c:1027:16: error: expected end of line before ‘ignored’
Simple.tab.c:1029:16: error: expected end of line before ‘pop’
   YY_IGNORE_MAYBE_UNINITIALIZED_END
                ^
Simple.tab.c:1039:1: error: unknown type name ‘YYSTYPE’
 YYSTYPE yylval;
 ^
Simple.tab.c: In function ‘yyparse’:
Simple.tab.c:1068:5: error: unknown type name ‘YYSTYPE’
     YYSTYPE yyvsa[YYINITDEPTH];
     ^
Simple.tab.c:1069:5: error: unknown type name ‘YYSTYPE’
     YYSTYPE *yyvs;
     ^
Simple.tab.c:1070:5: error: unknown type name ‘YYSTYPE’
     YYSTYPE *yyvsp;
     ^
Simple.tab.c:1080:3: error: unknown type name ‘YYSTYPE’
   YYSTYPE yyval;
   ^
Simple.tab.c:363:46: error: ‘YYSTYPE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
      ((N) * (sizeof (yytype_int16) + sizeof (YYSTYPE)) \
                                              ^
Simple.tab.c:1157:44: note: in expansion of macro ‘YYSTACK_BYTES’
           (union yyalloc *) YYSTACK_ALLOC (YYSTACK_BYTES (yystacksize));
                                            ^
Simple.tab.c:363:46: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
      ((N) * (sizeof (yytype_int16) + sizeof (YYSTYPE)) \
                                              ^
Simple.tab.c:1157:44: note: in expansion of macro ‘YYSTACK_BYTES’
           (union yyalloc *) YYSTACK_ALLOC (YYSTACK_BYTES (yystacksize));
                                            ^
Simple.y:60:26: error: request for member ‘id’ in something not a structure or union
   | INTEGER id_seq IDENTIFIER '.' { install( $3 ); }
                          ^
Simple.y:63:26: error: request for member ‘id’ in something not a structure or union
   | id_seq IDENTIFIER ',' { install( $2 );  }
                          ^
Simple.y:69:41: error: request for member ‘id’ in something not a structure or union
   | READ IDENTIFIER   { context_check( READ_INT, $2 ); }
                                         ^
Simple.y:71:39: error: request for member ‘id’ in something not a structure or union
   | IDENTIFIER ASSGNOP exp  { context_check( STORE, $1 ); }
                                       ^
Simple.y:72:17: error: request for member ‘lbls’ in something not a structure or union
   | IF exp   { $1 = (struct lbs *) newlblrec(); $1->for_jmp_false = reserve_loc();}
                 ^
Simple.y:72:64: error: request for member ‘lbls’ in something not a structure or union
   | IF exp   { $1 = (struct lbs *) newlblrec(); $1->for_jmp_false = reserve_loc();}
                                                                ^
Simple.y:73:17: error: request for member ‘lbls’ in something not a structure or union
     THEN commands   { $1->for_goto = reverse_loc(); }
                 ^
Simple.y:74:29: error: request for member ‘lbls’ in something not a structure or union
     ELSE    { back_patch( $1->for_jmp_false, JMP_FALSE,gen_label() );}
                             ^
Simple.y:76:28: error: request for member ‘lbls’ in something not a structure or union
     FI    { back_patch($1->for_goto,GOTO,gen_label());}
                            ^
Simple.y:77:16: error: request for member ‘lbls’ in something not a structure or union
   | WHILE    { $1 = (struct lbs *) newlblrec(); $1->for_goto = gen_label(); }
                ^
Simple.y:77:62: error: request for member ‘lbls’ in something not a structure or union
   | WHILE    { $1 = (struct lbs *) newlblrec(); $1->for_goto = gen_label(); }
                                                              ^
Simple.y:78:17: error: request for member ‘lbls’ in something not a structure or union
    exp   { $1->for_jmp_false = reserve_loc(); }
                 ^
Simple.y:81:33: error: request for member ‘lbls’ in something not a structure or union
     END    { gen_code( GOTO, $1->for_goto );back_patch( $1->for_jmp_false,JMP_FALSE,gen_label() );}
                                 ^
Simple.y:81:74: error: request for member ‘lbls’ in something not a structure or union
     END    { gen_code( GOTO, $1->for_goto );back_patch( $1->for_jmp_false,JMP_FALSE,gen_label() );}
                                                                          ^
Simple.y:83:34: error: request for member ‘intval’ in something not a structure or union
 exp :  NUMBER     { gen_code( LD_INT, $1 );}
                                  ^
Simple.y:84:39: error: request for member ‘id’ in something not a structure or union
  | IDENTIFIER    { context_check( LD_VAR, $1 );}
                                       ^
```

how can I fix it ?

Comment: You can't expect people here to parse your compiler messages for you. I too am not intimately familiar with Flex/Bison, but to me, many of these errors are self-explanatory. If these errors are from auto-generated code, either your Flex/Bison builds are incompatible with the compiler you use or you use incorrect options.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: It's a bison bug. See https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=733942 . If that's your downvote, you might want to reconsider.

Comment: Not mine - I hardly ever down-vote anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a reported bug in bison 3.0.2, which comes from the non-standard usage

```
 %union <union-name> {
    <union members
 }
```

When you do this, bison 3.0.2 incorrectly inserts a `#line` directive into the generated code before the `<union-name>`, which is normally not at the beginning of a line.

If you remove the name, then things will work but your union will be called `union YYSTYPE` instead of `union semrec`, which might turn out to be a problem. I'd suggest the following:

```
 %union
        semrec {
          // .. members ..
 }
```

All the other errors (probably) come from the syntax error in the `union` declaration.

The new-line before the union name should resolve the problem. I don't have an install of 3.0.2 handy, though, so no promises. I'll try to take another look at it tomorrow.

Comment: I removed <union-name> name like you said and there was an typing mistake in Simple.y I fixed it and now it's okay, thanks